# Unable to read data after NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am getting a json array from the server. The jsonOutput object shows 2 objects correctly. But am unable to display or extract the data. Could some one help me out. I tried 
the following way :

```
 for (id key in jsonOutput) {
          NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [jsonOutput objectForKey:key]);
        }
```

declaration : 
    NSDictionary *jsonOutput;

actualmethods :

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        data=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
    {
        [data appendData:theData];


       // if ([connection isEquals:connect1]){
            // this is request urlConnectionRecsender
       // }
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {

    jsonOutput= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];


    for (id key in jsonOutput) {
          NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [jsonOutput objectForKey:key]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You could pass in an error variable and inspect that object. If no error is written to the variable, check if you got an array or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

NSError *error;

```
jsonOutput= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if(error) 
    NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
```

If you don't know what is response type, then it is always a good practice to check respone type first

```
id responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
    if ([responseObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
       //Your response is a array
    }
    else if([responseObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        //Your response is a dictionary
    }
```

Your array contains NSDictionary

```
{ cropName = corn; cropOrderId = 1; cropPrice = 100; "farmer_id" = 1; orderStatus = pending; quantity = 5; }
```

use this code to get value

```
for(NSDictionary*dict in jsonObject) {

    NSArray *allKeysarr = [dic allKeys];

    for(NSString *key in allKeysarr) {

         NSLog(@"%@",[dic valueForKey:key]);
     }

}
```

Comment: No its not working the same errorr -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7518aa0

Comment: Then you responese is an array. Make jsonOutput to NSArray

Comment: I used the above code and its an array. but still i get the error even after changing the type to array. using for(id key in jsonOutput){
        NSLog(key);
    }

Comment: How are you accessing the value from array ?

Comment: Got the values now using for(id key in jsonOutput){
        NSLog(@"%@",key);
    }

.... as 
{
    cropName = corn;
    cropOrderId = 1;
    cropPrice = 100;
    "farmer_id" = 1;
    orderStatus = pending;
    quantity = 5;
} how do i fetch each one of them ?

Comment: Could you paste the json string here?

Comment: @user2569524 I updated my answer It may help you for reading values.

Answer (score 0):

first use error handling:

```
NSError *error;
jsonOutput= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"error: %@",error.description);
```

then access values with:

```
NSString *value1 = [jsonOutput objectForKey:@"YOUR_KEY1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath];

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:xmlData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its an array!");
    NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
    NSLog(@"jsonArray - %@",jsonArray);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"its probably a dictionary");
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
    NSLog(@"jsonDictionary - %@",jsonDictionary);
}
```

Try this once